Progressbar in form view displaying integer values instead of percentage
I want the progress bar in the form view to display integer values, like 20/50, instead of showing a percentage (e.g., 40%). Please provide a simple solution.
I tries different widgets but not getting the solutions please tell me the solution in Odoo build-in widget id possible.

show what you have attempted pls.
